# Moving Logo on action bar Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have put an image from my drawable folder and added it onto my action bar and would now like to move it left over beside the back arrow. Anyone any ideas on how to do this in Android Studio. Thanks

My Code is as fallows

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.mainlogo);
```

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at using a Toolbar instead of ActionBar?

Comment: No @Da-JinC would a be difficult to make

Comment: I don't think there's any other way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a Toolbar, the new way to make AppBars. It is more easily customized and reused, among other advantages.

[Android's docs](http://developer.android.com/training/appbar/setting-up.html) make it seem a lot harder than it really is. They use Toolbar but connect it to the AppBar API's still. If you use a lot of ActionBar utility methods like ActionBar.hide(), then it makes sense to call

```
setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
```

But it can actually be significantly easier.
[Why you don't need to setSupportActionBar](https://medium.com/@ZakTaccardi/goodbye-actionbar-apis-hello-toolbar-af6ae7b31e5d#.7hgdkrsvx)

According to the article above, if we don't use the AppBar API's we don't need the custom theme, onCreateOptionsMenu(), or any of the AppBar mess.

**Here is how to do Toolbars simply:**

1. Get [v7 appcompat](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v7-appcompat)
2. I *think* it is neccessary still to make your Activity extend AppCompatActivity
3. Add the following code:

At to the top of your layout resource file, inside the top level Layout of course:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
   android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
   android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
   android:elevation="4dp"
   android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
   app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

In your activity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ...
    //Get the toolbar
    Toolbar toolbar = ((Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar));
    //Set up the toolbar's navigation icon and behavior
    toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_close_white_24dp);
    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //whatever you want to happen on click
        }
    });
}
```

Optionally you can do things like:

```
toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.save_menu);
toolbar.setTitle("Hey");
```

Heres where the custom behavior you wanted comes in. If you want an ImageView in the toolbar, you simply add it to the layout resource:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
   android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
   android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
   android:elevation="4dp"
   android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
   app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/my_logo"/>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

In fact, if you want a title with custom styles, instead of banging your head against the wall trying to figure out Toolbar styling, simply add a TextView where the ImageView is. You can modify that however you want, and make it your title!